# my chrome extension popup opens after a few seconds, it's slow compared to other extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

When we click on the `extension button`, listed beside the address bar (where the URL appears), `popup.html` of the corresponding extension shows up. (of course, according to `manifest.json`)

When I click on lastPass, the popup appears instantly, but when I click on my custom-extension (contains nothing but popup.html), the mouse icon changes to loading for 1-2 seconds & then the popup opens up.

Did some digging on why my popup is so slow, the google-groups had something like

```
window.load=setTimeout(activate,0);
```

Unable to find any related documentation, or working sample.

Please help in figuring out why my extension popup is so slow, though the code contains nothing just the popup (beginner in chrome-extensions development).

### **Update**

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Sample Name",
  "description": "Sample Descriptoin",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <label>Enter HR Password</label>
            <input type='password' id='passwd'/>
            <button id='evaluateResults'>Evaluate</button>
            <ul id='results' style='width:100px;'>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src='popup.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
var totalCorrect=0, totalWrong=0;

document.getElementById('evaluateResults').addEventListener('click',function(){
    var passwd=document.getElementById('passwd').value;
    if(passwd==='123'){     
        var strCode="var scriptOptions = {role:'blank'};";
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: strCode,allFrames:true}, function(){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script_evaluate.js",allFrames:true});       
        });
    }else{
        alert("Incorrect Password");
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request);
    var ul=document.getElementById('results');
    var li=document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML=request.testName+" - "+(request.testResult?"Correct":"Wrong");
    ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: Show us the code; it's impossible to say why it takes a long time to load if we don't see what you are trying to load.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the parts you show.

Comment: @Xan so the mouse icon doesn't change to a loader for a second & then only the popup shows up ?

Comment: it works fine for me too... no waiting times

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What worked for was to add an empty background page.
This is not explained in the Google Documentation (or at least I did not find it), so it was more of a fluke, but seems to work.

The idea is that the plugin is loaded once when you come to the page (so before you even click), as opposed to being reloaded over and over again on each click.

In the manifest add something like:

```js
{
  //...
  "background": {
    "page": "bg.html"
  }
  //...
}
```

And the bg.html can just be an empty HTML file:

```html
<html>

</html>
```

Again - never found an explicit link or resource explaining why this should be done like this, and I am not sure it is the best practice, but it did work for me.

Comment: It doesn't work. When we try to add a "page" in the "background", we couldn't unpack(load) the extension in Google Chrome.

Comment: @BalasubramaniM - what error do you get? Did you triple check your manifest is according to the Google documentation? Please provide more information.

Comment: Works ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For an updated Manifest V3 solution, I found that you can simply preload the html file as an offscreen document. Just include the following code (or something similar) in a service worker or some other script.

```js
const preloadHTML = async () => {
    if (!await chrome.offscreen.hasDocument()) {
        await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
            url: "index.html", 
            reasons: [chrome.offscreen.Reason.DISPLAY_MEDIA],
            justification: "Helps with faster load times of popup"
        })
    }
}
```

<sup>As I doubt this was the intended use of offscreen documents, I put an arbitrary reason for the `createDocument` function.</sup>

Do note that you'll need to include the `offscreen` permission in `manifest.json`

```json
"permissions": [
    "offscreen"
  ],
```

This workaround should work as of now (May 2023), as the document's lifespan is currently unlimited if you don't specify `AUDIO_PLAYBACK` as the reason for creating it.

For more information, here's the [Official Chrome Offscreen reference page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen)
and a [Chromium discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/sDNbgeVHEEw) on offscreen document lifecycles.