# Slight loading delay with chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popup

For some reason, I have a very small delay when I click my extension before the popup is loaded.

It's a 1-2 second hiccup before the popup displays, while all my other extensions display the popup html immediately.

[image: loading]

As you can see above, there is even the loading cursor animation when I click the popup, which never happens for the other extensions.

Here is my popup html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    <title>Add a website to block</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="addWebsiteForm">
    Website Address: <input type="text" id="websiteAddress"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Website">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My popup.js

```
var addWebsiteForm;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  addWebsiteForm = document.getElementById("addWebsiteForm");
  addWebsiteForm.addEventListener('submit', addWebsite);
});

function addWebsite(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var websiteAddressInput = document.getElementById("websiteAddress");
  var websiteAddress = websiteAddressInput.value;
  var storedWebsites;

  chrome.storage.local.get('websites', function(objects) {

    if (!objects.websites) {
        storedWebsites = [];
    } else {
        storedWebsites = objects.websites;
    }

    storedWebsites.push({'address':websiteAddress});
    chrome.storage.local.set({'websites':storedWebsites});
    addWebsiteForm.reset();
    websiteAddressInput.focus();
  });
}
```

And my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Quizlet Extension",
  "description": "Go through your flashcards before moving onto a website",
  "version": "1.0",

  "options_page":"options.html",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I remember a similar question.. Can you try moving your `<script>` tag to the end of `<body>`?

Comment: No change. Actually, taking out the script line altogether gives me the same problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't really be reproducible. Try to search for issues at crbug.com and maybe opening a new one. While you do, try to repoduce it on another machine / on Chrome Canary.

Comment: @user3854397 Which version of Chrome are you using? Which operating system are you using? Someone else also had an issue with the popup (http://crbug.com/421778), but unfortunately the bug report did not provide enough auctionable information.

Comment: @RobW I am using Version 38.0.2125.111 m. I am on Windows 8.1 as well.

Comment: @user3854397 Could you try earlier versions of Chrome to see if it reproduces? 1. Use 7-zip to extract the offline installer 2. Use 7-zip again to extract the resulting chrome.7z file. 3. Start chrome.exe --user-data-dir=%TMP%\whatever and load your extension. If that does not reproduce the problem, close Chrome, COPY your full user data directory from your main Chrome profile (visit chrome://version to find the location of this directory), and start the old Chrome using this directory. If the problem does not persist, then the problem is probably caused by a specific version of Chrome.

Comment: Here are some old versions that you can try: https://robwu.nl/s/37.0.2062.124_chrome_installer.exe / https://robwu.nl/s/36.0.1985.49_chrome_installer.exe (let me know if you need more).

Comment: The problem has actually mysteriously disappeared. I'll let you know if it comes back.

Comment: Is this answer helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191671/chrome-extension-pauses-before-loading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [my chrome extension popup opens after a few seconds, it's slow compared to other extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276815/my-chrome-extension-popup-opens-after-a-few-seconds-its-slow-compared-to-other)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to add the `background` params to the `manifest` :

```
{
  ...
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  ...
}
```

Of course, need add a simple html file to the extension folder :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now open the Chrome Extension will be quickly without `no delay`.

The `background page` will be run `all the time`, it is always used to show notification.So we can make use of this feature, need't reopen the Extension which is the main reason of delay