# chrome browserAction is slow to open

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension that has a browserAction button. I have found that recently, the popup is slow to appear, taking maybe ~1.5 seconds to first appear.  I have only noticed this in the last 3-4 months; and I'm currently running chrome 55.0.2883.87 m.

Using timing from debugging, it appears that the delay is not within when my (javascript) code runs.

I am also seeing this same delay with other browserAction buttons for other extensions that I happen to use -- there is generally quite a "pregnant pause" after clicking a browserAction icon.

I created a very simple test extension with a browserAction having virtually no content, and, it did not have this noticeable delay.  So, I began to trim my other one, the one I'm seeing slow down, stripping it of functionality.  When I removed the following line of html from the popup, the performance returned:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="browserAction.css" />
```

I then substituted this (now commented out) with inline css, and the performance was still good.

So, I'm thinking that in the latest versions of chrome, a few dozen lines of css referenced via a link are causing browserAction buttons to delay popup appearance by over a second.

Is anyone else noticing the same?

---

(FYI, I have seen this question and it is not relevant to mine.
[my chrome extension popup opens after a few seconds, it's slow compared to other extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276815/my-chrome-extension-popup-opens-after-a-few-seconds-its-slow-compared-to-other)

I am using a persistent background page, which is different from the other question.  The popup slowness I'm observing also occurs regularly, not just the first time or if the browserAction isn't already loaded in a regular tab.)

Comment: https://crbug.com/649942

Comment: @wOxxOm, sure looks similar, though no mention specifically of css as culprit.  I did nothing more than inline my exact same css and performance is much better.  Still, maybe they're working on this in general; thanks for the info.

Comment: The culprit was discovered later in another issue merged into this one.

Comment: While this is interesting, and is sounds like the issue is already filed as a Chrome bug, it would make this question complete to have a *minimal* [mcve] with two different popup HTML contents which demonstrates the difference you see when moving the CSS inline.